# Substituting Hebrew letter variants

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

I have two functions that replace letters. In one function, I'm replacing a regular Hebrew letter with its final form, and the other function undoes this operation. (Consider it like lowercase/uppercase, except only a few letters have both forms.)

I created an object where the keys are the regular forms and the values are the final forms. In each function, I iterate over the object and run a regex - in one function it's `map[i]` -> `i`; the other is `i` -> `map[i]`.

Would it be worth it / even possible to abstract this `for` loop into a function?

```
var map = {
    כ: 'ך',
    מ: 'ם',
    נ: 'ן',
    פ: 'ף',
    צ: 'ץ'
};

exports.toFinal = function(text) {
    for (var i in map) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(i,'g'), map[i]);
    }
    return text;
}

exports.toRegular = function(text) {
    for (var i in map) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(map[i],'g'), i);
    }
    return text;
}
```

(`exports` is Node.js's `exports` object, and the code is implicitly running in a closure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* extract the logic of the for loop to a common function,
to be reused by both `exports.toFinal` and `exports.toRegular`,
by passing in a function as parameter:

```
function applyReplacements(text, patternReplacementPairGetter) {
    for (var i in map) {
        var pair = patternReplacementPairGetter(i, map[i]);
        var pattern = pair.pattern;
        var replacement = pair.replacement;
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), replacement);
    }
    return text;
}

function patternReplacementPair(pattern, replacement) {
    return {
        pattern: pattern,
        replacement: replacement
    };
}

exports.toFinal = function(text) {
    return applyReplacements(text, function(k, v) { return patternReplacementPair(k, v); });
}

exports.toRegular = function(text) {
    return applyReplacements(text, function(k, v) { return patternReplacementPair(v, k); });
}
```

Comment: Wow, that code is a lot longer than the original! Also, i wouldn't attach those other functions to the `exports` object, but just leave them in the implicit closure (this is NodeJS).

Comment: I don't see length as a concern when decomposing methods and reducing duplication of logic. As per your second point about closures, I updated my answer, and improved somewhat the naming

Answer (score 3):

I would opt for another implementation.

You iterate over your map and for each value, you replace a character in the source string. So for *n* characters in your map, you run *n* replacement operations for a length of *m*. Given, that *n* = *m*, that takes n^2 steps.

I would make two maps; one for each direction:
(for simplicity reasons, I chose latin letters)

```
var form1 = {
    'a':'A',
    'b':'B'
};

var form2 = {
    'A':'a',
    'B':'b'
};
```

If I need to know, whether there is a translation, I could do a simple operation `form1['a']` or `form1['x']`.

A translation - independent of the direction - could be defined as:

```
function translate(x){
  return (map[x])?map[x]:x;
}
```

Is a letter in the map, translate it, else return the original letter.

To specify the direction, you could define a closure, passing in the appropriate map:

```
 function makeTranslation(map){
    return function translate(x){
        return (map[x])?map[x]:x;
    }
}
```

If you want to translate more than one character, you have to split the string and translate each character. After that join the result:

```
function translate(expression, direction){
    return expression.split("").map(direction).join("");
}
```

Which results in two functions:

```
function toFinal(expression){
    return translate(expression, makeTranslation(form1));
}

function toRegular(expression){
    return translate(expression, makeTranslation(form2));
}
```

The resulting code looks like this:

```js
var form1 = {
        'a':'A',
        'b':'B'
};

var form2 = {
    'A':'a',
    'B':'b'
};

function makeTranslation(map){
    return function translate(x){
        return (map[x])?map[x]:x;
    }
}

function translate(expression, direction){
    return expression.split("").map(direction).join("");
}

function toFinal(expression){
    return translate(expression, makeTranslation(form1));
}

function toRegular(expression){
    return translate(expression, makeTranslation(form2));
}

console.log(toRegular(toFinal("aabbcbb"))==='aabbcbb');
console.log(toFinal(toRegular("AABBcBB"))==='AABBcBB');
```

Comment: An `invert()` function, such as the [one in Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#invert), would be useful.